# Accepting a path as a command line argument instead of an input in python

Tags: python, sorting, cmd, command-line-arguments

I am tasked with creating an app using python to sort files in a given directory.

I want the input path to be passed as a command line argument using
cmd_parser.add_argument()
instead of being accepted as normal input after running the code.

The code does what it's supposed to, but I don't want the path to be received as an input.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
import os
import shutil
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def main():
    cmd_parser = ArgumentParser(description="Application")
    cmd_parser.add_argument(
        '-v', '--version',
        action='version',
        version='Application v0.0.1',
        help='show version of the application'
    )
    cmd_parser.add_argument(
        '-h', '--help',
        action='help',
        help='Please enter a valid directory which contains the files to be sorted'
    )
    cmd_args = cmd_parser.parse_args()
    try:
        globals()[cmd_args.action](cmd_args.file)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[ERROR]', str(ex))
        sys.exit(1)


while True:
    directory = input("Please input the directory including the files: ")
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        print("Please input a valid directory")
    else:
        break

path = directory
os.chdir(path)
new_folder = "Sorted Files"
os.makedirs(new_folder)
path_2 = path+"/"+new_folder
os.chdir(path_2)
new_folder_doc = "Documents"
new_folder_texts = "Texts"
new_folder_images = "Images"
new_folder_other = "Other"
os.makedirs(new_folder_doc)
os.makedirs(new_folder_texts)
os.makedirs(new_folder_images)
os.makedirs(new_folder_other)


for file in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    if file_path.endswith('.png') or file_path.endswith('.gif') or file_path.endswith('.bmp') or\
            file_path.endswith('.jpg') or file_path.endswith('.jpeg') is True:
        shutil.move(file_path, new_folder_images)
        continue
    if file_path.endswith('.txt') or file_path.endswith('.ini') or file_path.endswith('.log') is True:
        shutil.move(file_path, new_folder_texts)
        continue
    if file_path.endswith('.pdf') or file_path.endswith('.docx') or file_path.endswith('.doc') or\
            file_path.endswith('.xls') or file_path.endswith('.xlsx') or file_path.endswith('.csv') is True:
        shutil.move(file_path, new_folder_doc)
        continue
    if file_path.endswith('.docx') or file_path.endswith('.txt') or file_path.endswith('.bmp') or \
            file_path.endswith('.png') is not True:
        shutil.move(file_path, new_folder_other)
        continue

my_folder = path  # your path here
count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_folder):
    count += len([fn for fn in files if fn.endswith(".pdf") or fn.endswith(".docx")
                  or fn.endswith(".doc") or fn.endswith(".xls") or fn.endswith(".xlsx") or fn.endswith(".csv")
                  or fn.endswith(".jpeg") or fn.endswith(".jpg") or fn.endswith(".bmp") or fn.endswith(".gif")
                  or fn.endswith(".png") or fn.endswith(".txt") or fn.endswith(".ini") or fn.endswith(".log")])
print(f"Organized {count} files")
```

Error resulting from fixed code (It's also not doing what it's supposed to anymore)

```
usage: StackTestSorter.py [-h] [-v] directory
StackTestSorter.py: error: the following arguments are required: directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having:

```py
def main():
    cmd_parser = ArgumentParser(description="Application")
    cmd_parser.add_argument(
        '-v', '--version',
        action='version',
        version='Application v0.0.1',
        help='show version of the application'
    )
    cmd_parser.add_argument(
        '-h', '--help',
        action='help',
        help=''
    )
    cmd_args = cmd_parser.parse_args()
    try:
        globals()[cmd_args.action](cmd_args.file)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[ERROR]', str(ex))
        sys.exit(1)


while True:
    directory = input("Please input the directory including the files: ")
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        print("Please input a valid directory")
    else:
        break

path = directory
```

have (removing the `--help` argument as this will be added automatically):

```
cmd_parser = ArgumentParser(description="Application")
cmd_parser.add_argument(
    '-v', '--version',
    action='version',
    version='Application v0.0.1',
    help='show version of the application'
)
cmd_parser.add_argument(
    "directory",  # this will be a positional argument
    help="a valid directory which contains the files to be sorted",
)

cmd_args = cmd_parser.parse_args()

path = cmd_args.directory
```

Comment: This solved my problem, however after running it in the terminal, although it is doing what it's supposed to, some errors are being raised for whatever reason. Could you possibly have a look at that? Thank you very much.  @Matt Pitkin

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: The error is too long for me to post it here, is there another way I could send it to you? @Matt Pitkin

Comment: Can you edit the original post and add on the error at the end.

Comment: Done @Matt Pitkin

Comment: You can remove the lines where you add the --help argument, as when you include a `description` on initialising the `ArgumentParser` it will by default set that to be the help message. I'll edit the answer above to remove the help lines.

Comment: Alright, that was solved, but now it says a 'directory' argument is required (see edited in original post) @Matt Pitkin

Comment: Isn't that what you want? I.e., you wanted to have to supply the directory as a command line argument, so if you don't supply it the script will fail as you are seeing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250227/discussion-between-juj-and-matt-pitkin).

Answer (score 2):

if I understood you correctly all you need to do is add one more argument, something like:

```
cmd_parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", help="", required=True, default=False)
```

and then after cmd_args you can do:

```
path = cmd_args.path
```